# C++20 Coroutines, await_resume return lvalue, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

#### Happening

I want to store **move only** data to `promise_type`, and get it in coroutine. I try return return lvalue from `await_resume()`. The result is compilation is successful but **Segmentation fault** appears during execution.

How can I improve?

---

#### Environment

- OS: WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04
- Complier: gcc 10.3
- Command: g++ -std=c++20 -fcoroutines main.cpp

---

#### Code

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
#include <memory>

struct task
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        using data_type = std::unique_ptr<int>;

        task get_return_object() noexcept
        {
            return task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this));
        }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() {}
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }

        data_type data; // my data
    };

    void set_data(promise_type::data_type&& data) // [2] set my data
    {
        handle.promise().data = std::forward<promise_type::data_type>(data);
    }

    void resume()
    {
        handle.resume();
    }

    task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle) : handle(handle) {}

private:
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
};

struct awaitalbe
{
    bool await_ready() { return true; }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<task::promise_type> handle) { this->handle = handle; }
    task::promise_type::data_type&& await_resume()
    {
        return std::move(handle.promise().data); // [3] get my data
    }

    std::coroutine_handle<task::promise_type> handle;
};

task f()
{
    auto p2 = co_await awaitalbe{}; // [4] Segmentation fault here. after [3]
    std::cout << (*p2) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto task1 = f();

    task::promise_type::data_type p1 = std::make_unique<task::promise_type::data_type::element_type>(10);
    task1.set_data(std::move(p1)); // [1] set my data

    task1.resume();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `struct awaitable`, you have:

```cpp
bool await_ready() { return true; }
```

To clarify, `await_ready` is a mechanism used to determine whether the result corresponding to an awaitable is ready or not. If it is ready, then there is really no good reason to suspend the calling coroutine (i.e the one that `co_await`s the awaitable) and wait for the result - just call `await_resume` which retrieves the result.

It allows you do something like:

```cpp
bool await_ready() {
  if (will_read_block()) {
     return false;
  }
  read_some_data_from_file();
  return true;
}
```

so that non-blocking reads will complete synchronously.

In your case, you always return true. This tells the runtime: when a coroutine awaits an `awaitable`, never suspend that coroutine and directly call `await_resume`, skipping the suspension and `await_suspend` altogether. Indeed, if you set a breakpoint in `await_suspend` (or use a print statement if your debugger does not like coroutines) in `await_suspend`, you will find out that it never gets called. Therefore, you never actually assign anything to the `handle` member in your `awaitable` struct, resulting in undefined behaviour when you attempt to get a promise out of it.

The solution: just return `false` from `await_ready`.